# Visual Studio 2019 LLVM clang flags

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, clang, llvm

​Hello, i choosed Platform toolset LLVM (clang-cl)
[image]

When i build project, visual studio start clang-cl.exe, how i can pass clang arguments(flags)?

Answer (score 1):

It is the same mechanism used to pass options manually with the Visual C++ compiler, in that you can pass them by adding to "Additional Options" under:
"Configuration Properties", "C/C++", "Command Line":

[image: Configuration Properties]

To find out which subset of clang options are available, bring up a Visual Studio 2019 command prompt and type: clang-cl -?

This will first list the Microsoft compatibility options (i.e. the ones VC++ uses) and then follows up with the Clang options.